# Assembly error when Coded UI Test starts on a virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio, virtual-machine, coded-ui-tests

I have made a Coded UI Test-project with VS 2015, which shall run on a virtual machine.

On the VM VS 2013 as well as 2015 are installed and the Test Agent from VS 2013 is online.

When i test it per vstest.console.exe on the VM, the tests are working fine.

But when i connect on my PC with VS 2013 or 2015 to the team project (it is in GIT) and start a team project-build, which starts the automated test via the Test Agent on the VM, the Agent deploys the build, calls the test case and then i receive the following error:

*The component test adaptor has released the following exception: At least one type in the Assembly cannot be loaded. Call away the LoaderExceptions quality if you need further information.*

When i take a look to the event protocols on the VM i see the following error message:

*The description for the event-ID "0" from the spring "VSTTExecution" was not found. Either the component which releases this event not on the local computer is installed, or the installation is damaged. They can instal the component on the local computer or repair.
If the event on another computer has appeared, the announcement information with the event had to be stored.
The following information was stored with the event:
(QTAgent32_40.exe, PID 3732, Thread 14) Unit test adaptor threw exception: System. Reflection. ReflectionTypeLoadException: At least one type in the Assembly cannot be loaded. Call away the LoaderExceptions quality if you need further information.
   with system. Reflection. Run time modules. GetTypes (run time modules modules)
   with system. Reflection. Run time modules. GetTypes ()
   with system. Reflection. Assembly. GetTypes ()
   in Microsoft. VisualStudio. Test tools. TestTypes. Unit. UnitTestExecuter. GetAssemblyInfo (Assembly assembly)
   in Microsoft. VisualStudio. Test tools. TestTypes. Unit. UnitTestExecuter. GetTypeInfo (Type type, Boolean checkAlreadyExaminedType)
   in Microsoft. VisualStudio. Test tools. TestTypes. Unit. UnitTestExecuter. GetTypeInfo (Type type)
   in Microsoft. VisualStudio. Test tools. TestTypes. Unit. UnitTestExecuter. ResolveMethods ()
   in Microsoft. VisualStudio. Test tools. TestTypes. Unit. UnitTestExecuter. Initialize (UnitTestResult result, UnitTestRunner runner, ConsoleOutputRedirector redirector)
   in Microsoft. VisualStudio. Test tools. TestTypes. Unit. UnitTestRunner. Run (UnitTestElement test, ITestContext testContext, Boolean isLoadTest, Boolean useMultipleCpus)
The announcement resource exists, but the announcement was not found in the sign result and announcement table*

How can i find out, what has gone wrong?
I already activated the logging in the Test Agent config files, but the logs where not much better than the other messages.

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I've found it!
VS 2015 doesn't support test agents.
What a pity!

[Test Agents Support for Visual Studio 2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gopinath/archive/2015/02/27/test-agents-support-for-visual-studio-2015.aspx)